# Find the maximum benifit value from a sub-set of non-prefix neighbours?

Tags: string, algorithm, prefix

[image]

1 < n <= 4 x 10^5
Length of each string can be up to 11
Each string contains only uppercase letters

Example - If there are 3 strings, A, B and AE, output is 200.
Explanation - S = {"A", "B", "AE"}

Strings A and AE are prefix neighbors, so they cannot both be in Mark's subset of S. String B has no prefix neighbor, so we include it in Mark's subset.

To maximize the benefit value, we choose AE and B for our subset. We then calculate the following benefit values for the chosen subset:

```
Benefit value of AE = 65+69 = 134
Benefit value of B = 66
```

Total benefit value = 134 + 66 = 200.

Comment: So, what is the exact question? Also, if you just copy a problem from somewhere, a link attributing the source would be nice.

Comment: It's a problem from a [HackerRank contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/rookierank-2/challenges/prefix-neighbors)

Answer (score 1):

Insert the input words into a [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) and splice out the non key words. Compute the [maximum-weight independent set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544240/algorithm-to-find-max-independent-set-in-a-tree) of the tree; the link goes to an unweighted algorithm, so you'll need to replace `1` by the weight of the node as defined by this question. All of this is linear-time.