# Algorithm to prune nodes in network, achieve maximum number of isolates (python networkx)

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I have networks (large&small) which I need to prune until only isolates are left. I would like to maximize the number of isolates. Is there an algorithm to do this? also if its more complex ? (e.g. on the bottom there may be connected nodes as well)

consider this simple example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,7), (4,8),
 (1,2+9), (2+9,3+9), (2+9,4+9), (3+9,5+9), (3+9,6+9), (4+9,7+9), (4+9,8+9) ])
```

Here, the optimal solution is deleting node 1,3,4,11 and 12.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want to calculate the [Maximum Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) (which is *NP-hard* for *general graphs*). (Wikipedia also mentions the name *vertex packing*).

Networkx has an [approximation algorithm](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.independent_set.maximum_independent_set.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.independent_set.maximum_independent_set).

Maybe an approximation is not enough for you (and i think there is no prebuild alternative).

According to the wikipedia-link above, there is an exact algorithm available in [igraph](http://igraph.org/redirect.html).

Also keep in mind, that this approximation-algorithm is for *general graphs*, so it might be very much possible, that there are better approaches for trees.

**Edit:** (Without checking) [This SO-answer presents an algorithm for trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544240/algorithm-to-find-max-independent-set-in-a-tree) (and the question is a possible duplicate).

Comment: cool, I don't know the exact terminology, but this sounds like it.

Comment: i can delete my question